# Erro app android 5

Tags: java, android

Desenvolvi um android app que funciona perfeito, porem não roda no android 5, não sei mais o que fazer ...
Segue o log cat :

```html
11-19 20:36:27.387 24358-24358/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-19 20:36:27.414 24358-24368/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
11-19 20:36:28.085 24358-24373/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 266MB to 256MB
11-19 20:36:28.104 24358-24358/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 266MB to 256MB
11-19 20:36:28.104 24358-24358/? I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 21(848B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 250MB/256MB, paused 580us total 5.209ms
11-19 20:36:28.119 24358-24358/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 266MB to 256MB
11-19 20:36:28.119 24358-24358/? I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 250MB/256MB, paused 831us total 15.013ms
11-19 20:36:28.119 24358-24358/? I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 22MB allocation
11-19 20:36:28.134 24358-24358/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 266MB to 256MB
11-19 20:36:28.134 24358-24358/? I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 250MB/256MB, paused 982us total 14.828ms
11-19 20:36:28.135 24358-24358/? E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 24049292 byte allocation with 5599284 free bytes and 5MB until OOM"
11-19 20:36:28.136 24358-24358/? D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
11-19 20:36:28.136 24358-24358/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process: pack, PID: 24358
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 24049292 byte allocation with 5599284 free bytes and 5MB until OOM
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2426)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2333)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3735)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:634)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:111)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:64)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:60)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:101)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:926)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:980)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at pack.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:40)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
11-19 20:36:28.146 24358-24358/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
11-19 20:36:29.437 24358-24368/? I/art: Ignoring second debugger -- accepting and dropping
11-19 20:36:34.265 24358-24372/? I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 258MB to 256MB
```

Obrigado

Comment: Pelo erro, seu bitmap está ultrapassando a quantidade de memória disponível.

Comment: hmm ou seja o tamanho esta excedendo o limite ? ql o tamanho max?

Comment: Isso. Bem, essa é uma pergunta não tão fácil de responder, pode depender da memória disponível. Nos meus testes com bitmap, se você rodar no emulador vai facilitar pegar esses erros OOME mais facilmente do que se testasse num dispositivo real. Já tive erros assim no emulador e no dispositivo real funcionava normalmente (o que não quer dizer que iria funcionar sempre).  Tente dar uma olhada nesse link, que mostra como carregar bitmaps grandes de maneira eficiente: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @Luiz funcionou no real, mas o android 5 não funciona... Tem algum tamanho que possa usar que é certeza que funcione ?

Comment: @Luiz e amigos, o problema esta em uma imagem de fundo que tenho, pois se retiro ela funciona... A imagem 800 x 1200 , alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dentro da pasta res crie a pasta drawable-nodpi e coloque seu bitmap dentro dela